# PageName expression to return field value after each page break

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table row grouped on REF with page breaks between each new value for REF. I want the page name to be the value for REF. I thought this would be a simple:

```
=Fields!REF.Value
```

However that is returning only the first value for REF, with every subsequent page name being called REF(2), REF(3) etc. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and pagename configuration details in order to reproduce your problem

Comment: A lucky guess is that you have set the pagename of REF to the parent group, instead of the group itself.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that SSRS2008 does not support pagenames, I think that was introduced in a later version.